# Hibernate Too Lazy

Tags: hibernate

I have a single Parent/Child `@OneToMany` where the collection is a `Set` (no dups). I get the below error if I try to access the child from the Parent on the server.

If I pass the Parent to the client side via `request.setAttribute` and access the Parent using JSTL, I can access the Child objects members directly. The Parent/Childs have getters/Setters.

I'm using Tomcat 6.0.32, Spring 3.1.0, JDK6, Hibernate 3.

**Parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SUSER")
public class SUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int su_id;

    @Column(name="displayname", nullable=true, 
    columnDefinition="varchar", length=50, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private String displayname;

    @Column(name="last_activity", nullable=true, columnDefinition="datetime", 
    insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private String last_activity;

    @Column(name="ldapuser", nullable=true, columnDefinition="varchar", 
    length=50, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private String ldapuser;

    @OneToMany
    @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name="SU_ID")
    @JoinColumn(name="su_id", insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private Set<SUserAttributes> suattr = new HashSet<SUserAttributes>();
```

**Child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SUSER_ATTRIBUTES")
public class SUserAttributes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int sua_id;

    @Column(name="su_id")
    private int su_id;

    @Column(name="sua_key", nullable=true, columnDefinition="varchar", 
    length=64, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private String sua_key;

    @Column(name="sua_value", nullable=true, columnDefinition="varchar", 
    length=128, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    private String sua_value;
```

**DAO**

```
package com.oasis.implementation.dao;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

import com.oasis.implementation.ClientInfo;
import com.oasis.implementation.SUser;

public class SUserDaoImpl implements SUserDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(ClientDownloadsDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("implementationSessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<SUser> getAllSUsers(){
        List<SUser> suList = null;
        Session session = null;

        try
        {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            suList = session.createQuery("from SUser").list();          
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {           
            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        }   
        finally
        {
            if (session != null)
            {           
                session.close();
            }   
        }       

        return suList;      

    }

    @Override
    public List<SUser> getSUserById(int su_id) {
        Session session = null;
        SUser sUser = null;
        LinkedList<SUser> suList = new LinkedList<SUser>();

        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            sUser = (SUser) session.get(SUser.class, su_id);
            suList.add(sUser);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }

        return suList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SUser> getUserByLdap(String ldapuser){
        Session session = null;
        int user_id = 0;
        List<SUser> suList = null;

        try
        {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            SQLQuery sqlq = session.createSQLQuery("select su_id from 
            suser where ldapuser = '" + ldapuser + "'");
            user_id = (Integer)sqlq.uniqueResult();
            suList = getSUserById(user_id);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {           
            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
        }   
        finally
        {
            if (session != null)
            {           
                session.close();
            }   
        }       

        return suList;      

    }
}
```

**Error message**

```
    Hibernate: select suser0_.su_id as su1_11_0_, suser0_.displayname as 
displayn2_11_0_, suser0_.last_activity as last3_11_0_, suser0_.ldapuser as l
    dapuser11_0_ from SUSER suser0_ where suser0_.su_id=?
    ERROR - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.oasis.implementation.SUser.suattr, no session or session was closed
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.oasis.implementation.SUser.suattr, no session or
     session was closed
            at
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is happening because you're trying to access a lazily loaded collection (that means the collection hasn't been really fetched from the DB yet) once the Hibernate session is closed. So, no means of getting back to the DB to fetch the children. You could either:

- Force-load the association when the `Session` is still open, with a call to `Hibernate.initialize(parent.getSuattr());`
- Create a specific query for that use case with explicit `join fetch` statements.
- Modify the mapping to eagerly fetch the association if you're always going to query the children whenever you query the parent.
- Adopt the [OpenSessionInView](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView) pattern. This pattern opens an Hibernate session when a request is about to be processed (usually in a `Filter`), and keeps it open until it has been fully processed. Take into account that this approach might not be suitable for your current design (can require redesign), and should be used carefully, as it has some pitfalls that can really mess things up.

Comment: I took the EAGER fetch approach.

Comment: I don't see were to accept an answer. There's no like/dislike icon.

Comment: I understand that getting an object using the get(Object.class, id) method doesn't get the object but a reference(proxy) to the Object. That in order for Hibernate to get the object, one needs to access an other data member of the object on the server side. I tried this on the server side and didn't get the object. ????

Comment: @user931501 Once you query the object, you'll be able to query its lazily-fetched multiple-valued properties as long as the session is still open. If they're eagerly fetched you should have no problems querying the properties. Regarding accepting answers, just check the green mark next to its score as shown on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem of your code is, you opened a session/transaction and close/commit it in a DAO finder method.

Transaction (and hence, Hibernate Session) should be kept open for the scope of unit-of-work.  For example, transaction should be open/committed before and after an Application Service method invocation, so that every works done in that app service method will be all in one transaction.  (OpenSessionInView share similar rationale, it is just the "unit-of-work" is even longer in such case)

Comment: I added the EAGER fetch to my @OneToMany and its working now.

Comment: You should know the reason behind.  Adding EAGER may solve some cases but if you keep on using current approach you are going to face more problems, because it is a fundamental architectural design flaw.

Comment: Uhh the transaction the whole transaction "is" in the finder method. The Open session > Get the data > Close the session is all that is needed.

Comment: > so that every works done in that app service method will be all in one transaction< I don't see how you could miss the fact that the unit of work is being done with in the method, the session is not required to be opened before the invocation of the service method call in order to complete all works. In or Out the work is being done.

Comment: The EAGER fetch fits this design, I'll evaluate an other fetch type in my next design. The design was to create a Parent/Child were the Parent well no need to explain details of Parent/Child. Just to say at this point in the app I want both the Parent & Child at once. I did think that getting the Parent and accessing the child member would give me the Child without any effort. I guess I'm getting too comfortable with Spring and IOC.

Comment: I didn't miss the fact that session is opened in the finder method of DAO, that's what I pointed out in my first sentence.  The problem I tried to point out is, DAO is NOT an appropriate place for transaction (and hence, unit-of-work).  In most case, it will work as what you expected (effortless access of child), given that you have define the transaction boundary appropriately. (which you are not doing it right currently)

Comment: I'm following, learning Hibernate by reading "Java Persistence with Hibernate". How did you learn Hibernate?

Comment: Your book is one of the major sources I learnt Hibernate in the past too.  However I believe that book won't teach you how your application should be designed (e.g. where is the appropriate place for txn boundary etc), for which mainly I learnt from my experience

Comment: Well I'm a Contractor on an existing project that has Services in place. To keep in sync, not tip the boat, I'm following the existing design. The service I had created has no need to go out of the box. It's not that complex in term of tx, just get a dataset and done.

Comment: By the way diff between get() and load()? get() returns null if the record doesn't exist, wont hit the database if there is a ref in the cache, load() generates an exception NoRecordFound I believe if the record doesn't exist. I haven't found info on it's handling a record that does exist other that retrieving the record. But what overhead, does it hit the cache things like that.

Comment: First, no matter it is contract staff or not, as a developer I think he has obligation to raise out any design issue.  Especially this is such a irrational design which shouldn't been taken.  You are not doing something out-of-box, it is just a normal way to develop.  Second, for difference between get() and load(), it has been answered hundred times here in SO.  Do some research first and if you have anything that is not answered, feel free to raise another question in SO